# Читаю лист с данными в формате txt, out of range

Tags: python

Ошибка out of index Пытаюсь получить значения из файла txt, как я понимаю в конце файла есть один символ при попытки его применить срез, появляется эта ошибка, каким if можно избавиться от этого?

```
d_airports = {}
file = open("list_airports.txt", encoding="utf-8" ,mode ='r')
for i in file.readlines():

    if i !=  '\\t':
        print(i.split(' — ')[1].split(', ')[0])
        d_airports[i[0:3]] = i.split(' — ')[1].split(', ')[0]

file.close()
```

последняя строчка файла ZZV — Занесвилл, США, Занесвилл
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше проверять на пустую строку так:

```
if i.strip():
    # действия
```

Т.е. если после отбрасывания пробельных символов из строки остаётся не пустая строка, то делаем действия, иначе пропускаем такую строку.

Ну либо стандартный подход через ловлю исключений:

```
try:
    # действия
except:
    print("Случилась ошибка!")
```

Answer (score 1):

А может быть так:

```
for i in file.readlines():

    print(i.split(' — ')[1].split(', ')[0])
    d_airports[i[0:3]] = i.split(' — ')[1].split(', ')[0]
    if i ==  'zzv':
        break
```

Если Вы на 100% увкерены, что "zzv" это **последняя** строка.

Comment: хардкодинг - не очень почти всегда